Encountering 'fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output' error while cloning GitHub repository - How to resolve?
can anyone tell me how to solve it:
C:\> git clone https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla
Cloning into 'carla'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 87670, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2621/2621), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1286/1286), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 2418 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I use SSH instead of HTTPS: git clone git@github.com:carla-simulator/carla.git
but it is not working.
